# Picasso в цикле, создается ли он каждый раз?

Tags: java, android, picasso

При данном коде, Picasso создается каждый раз или же там существует что-то, что не позволяет создавать один и тот же объект Picasso?

Код:

```
while(mDownload == false){
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.get().load(URL).into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            mDownload = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Picasso.get()` будет возвращать один и тот же объект, это синглетон.

[Исходный код](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/version-two-e/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java#L676):

```
public static Picasso get() {
    if (singleton == null) {
      synchronized (Picasso.class) {
        if (singleton == null) {
          if (PicassoProvider.context == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("context == null");
          }
          singleton = new Builder(PicassoProvider.context).build();
        }
      }
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

Comment: @gli9red Спасибо за ответ, но в итоге из-за цикла, он каждый раз пересоздается и начинает загружать изображение заново или там существует что-то, что не позволяет создавать один и тот же объект Picasso и просто продолжает загрузку первого вызова Picasso?

Comment: @InnaAhtina, не знаю, могу предложить решение как создавать новый объект, не используя синглетон: `new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build().load(URL).into(imageView, new Callback() {`

Comment: Спасибо за прекрасный пример, но подскажите, ваше предложение с Builder для создания нового объекта как в данной ситуации поможет? Просто с Builder пока ещё не сталкивалась

Comment: На каждую итерацию цикла будет создан новый объект `Picasso`, у которого будет вызван метод `load`

Comment: спасибо, уже всё проверила благодаря вашему ответу. Вопрос решен, сейчас отмечу ваш ответ как правильный. Спасибо вам за столь скорый ответ, вы действительно помогли.

Comment: @InnaAhtina, пожалуйста :)